# Different AES encrypt in Eclipse and a JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption, encoding, jar

I work on a project using AES to encrypt data through TCP but i have an issue without any answer.

I try to test my soft in Eclipse and no error occurs. But, when i compile it as JAR file, the encryption change.

Here is my sources :

```
private final static String SECRETE_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private final static String IV = "0000000000000000";

/**
 * Encrypt the message with the secrete key in parameter
 */
public static String encrypt(String message) throws Exception {
    // The input length to encrypt should be a multiple of 16
    while (message.length() % 16 != 0) {
        message += " ";
    }

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");

    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(SECRETE_KEY.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));

    byte[] cipherByteArray = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    String cipherMsg = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cipherByteArray.length; i++) {
        cipherMsg += (char) cipherByteArray[i];
    }

    return cipherMsg;
}

/**
 * Decrypt the message with the secrete key in parameter
 */
public static String decrypt(String cipherMsg) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");

    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(SECRETE_KEY.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));

    byte[] cipherByteArray = new byte[cipherMsg.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < cipherMsg.length(); i++) {
        cipherByteArray[i] = (byte) cipherMsg.charAt(i);
    }

    return new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherByteArray));
}
```

I was thinking it was a encoding issue and set all in UTF-8 (sources and messages) but i use this JAR file in another Eclipse project as a library and AES works properly.

Does anyone have a clue ?

EDIT 1 :
I use a ANT build

```
<project default="all" basedir="." name="JAR - MyProject">

    <property name="jarFile" value="MyJar.jar" />

    <path id="libraries">
      <fileset dir="lib/">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
    </path>

    <pathconvert property="lib.classpath" pathsep=" ">
      <path refid="libraries"/>
      <flattenmapper/>
    </pathconvert>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete file="dist/${jarFile}"/>
        <delete dir="build" />
        <mkdir dir="dist" />
        <mkdir dir="build" />
    </target>

    <target name="buildJar" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes" />

        <copy todir="build/classes">
            <fileset dir="classes" includes="**/*.*"/>
        </copy>

        <jar jarfile="dist/${jarFile}" basedir="build/classes" compress="true" excludes="**/*.java">
              <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MyMainClass" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${lib.classpath}" />
              </manifest>   
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="all" depends="buildJar" />

</project>
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly with "the encryption change"?

Comment: In Eclipse for example, a String A is encrypt has a String B.
In the JAR file, the same String A is encrypt has a String C. 
String B and C are totally different and i can't decrypt String C.
NB: i don't encrypt it twice ^^

Comment: Sorry to answer this late, i didn't saw your comment

Comment: I can't reproduce you error. Everything works fine on my system. How do you create the jar?

Comment: I search for long but it seems i can't answer so i edit my question

Comment: But as i said, if i compile the project as JAR and use it in Eclipse as a library in another project, all works properly. I only have problems when i try to use the JAR out of Eclipse ..

Comment: SSL is the best way to encrypt data over TCP

Comment: @artbristol No flood please. It's not an answer to my problem, it's an asymetric cryptography and useless at my layer. I just look for a solution to my problem and it's not located in the protocol.

Comment: @Kraiss SSL/TLS is uses symmetric ciphers for data transfer. Asymmetric ciphers are used in SSL/TLS for authentication and key agreement. SSL/TLS also ensures message integrity which is often necessary to providing confidentiality.

Comment: @Dev Yes symetric keys after authentification and that can't be used in my case. By the way i don't search for a different way to encrypt my data but a fix for my problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your eclipse, go to Preferences > General > Content Types
Under 'Content Types', select 'JAR Content'. Then in 'Default Encoding' input (at the bottom) enter 'UTF-8' and update.

Also in 'Text', Select 'Jar Manifest file' and change the encoding to UTF-8.

This should solve your problem. If the problem still persists you can try with a different encoding. (Note that the eclipse editor will only enable the 'update' button when it finds a proper encoding format is entered).

Comment: I fix my problem. It was a problem with the Cipher.
Thanks anyway ;)